# What is the optimal way to retrieve a list of sorted dates in a list of sorted periods in python?

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, complexity

Suppose I have a list with N sorted dates and M non-overlapping sorted periods with start date, end date (inclusive), and a tax rate for example. I have to make an efficient algorithm retrieve all tax rates for all dates. If there is not period including this date it should raise an error.

Given the brute-force approach I could have a O(N * M) with two nested loops. It is possible to break the inner loop when one date is found (maintains the code worst-case complexity). Another optimization would be to store the index of last period, since the lists are sorted, then I believe I got O(N + M). Is there a more optimal way of doing that? Maybe using other data structures?

Working code in Python:

```
import collections
import datetime
import sys
from typing import List

RatePeriod = collections.namedtuple("RatePeriod", ["start_date", "end_date", "rate"])

periods = [
    RatePeriod(datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 3), datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 1), 10.7),
    RatePeriod(datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 2), datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 2), 20.5),
    RatePeriod(datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 3), datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 2), 37.8),
]

def get_rates(dates: List[datetime.datetime]) -> List[float]:
    rates = []
    last_period = 0
    for idx, date in enumerate(dates, 1):
        for idx2 in range(last_period, len(periods)):
            period = periods[idx2]
            last_period = idx2
            if period.start_date <= date <= period.end_date:
                rates.append(period.rate)
                break
        if len(rates) < idx:
            sys.exit("No period found for date: {}".format(date))
    return rates


series = [
    datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 20),
    datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 6),
    datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 14),
]

result = get_rates(series)
expected = [10.7, 10.7, 37.8]
assert result == expected
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your algorithm seems fine, it seems you brought it down in complexity enough. I have thought about it and couldn't think of anything better.

Still, the code can be rewritten to be more Pythonic:

```py
import collections
import sys
import timeit
from datetime import datetime as dt
from typing import List

RatePeriod = collections.namedtuple("RatePeriod", ["start_date", "end_date", "rate"])

periods = [
    RatePeriod(dt(2019, 1, 3), dt(2019, 4, 1), 10.7),
    RatePeriod(dt(2019, 4, 2), dt(2019, 12, 2), 20.5),
    RatePeriod(dt(2019, 12, 3), dt(2020, 1, 2), 37.8),
    RatePeriod(dt(2020, 1, 3), dt(2020, 12, 2), 41.3),
    RatePeriod(dt(2020, 12, 3), dt(2021, 1, 2), 52.7),
]


series = [
    dt(2019, 2, 20),
    dt(2019, 3, 6),
    dt(2020, 1, 5),
    dt(2020, 12, 5),
    # dt(2022, 1, 1),  # error, no period found
]


def get_rates(dates: List[dt]) -> List[float]:
    rates = []
    last_period = 0
    for idx, date in enumerate(dates, 1):
        for idx2 in range(last_period, len(periods)):
            period = periods[idx2]
            last_period = idx2
            if period.start_date <= date <= period.end_date:
                rates.append(period.rate)
                break
        if len(rates) < idx:
            sys.exit("No period found for date: {}".format(date))
    return rates


def get_rates_generator(dates: List[dt]) -> List[float]:
    last_period = 0
    for date in dates:
        for idx_period, period in enumerate(periods[last_period:], start=last_period):
            if period.start_date <= date <= period.end_date:
                last_period = idx_period
                break
        else:
            sys.exit(f"No period found for date: {date}")
        yield period.rate


result = get_rates(series)
result_generator = list(get_rates_generator(series))

setup = "from __main__ import get_rates, get_rates_generator, series"
print("Old:", timeit.timeit("get_rates(series)", setup=setup))
print("New:", timeit.timeit("list(get_rates_generator(series))", setup=setup))

expected = [10.7, 10.7, 41.3, 52.7]

assert result == result_generator == expected
```

where the printed output will be somewhere in the ballpark of

```bsh
Old: 2.3620867
New: 2.3765742000000003
```

aka, the rewritten function is not actually faster.
A couple notes on the new, suggested approach:

- imported `datetime.datetime` as `dt` for readability; `from datetime import datetime` is likely confusing and should be avoided
- handling the case of not finding an item is nicely handled using `for`/`else`. In fact, it is one of the prime uses of `for`/`else`. The `else` block is run if no `break` was encountered for the entire loop. Since there is already a `break` in place, it is straightforward to implement the `else` block. This also gets rid of having to `enumerate` over `dates`.
- instead of building and returning a list, a generator only *yields* on request. Having found a match, the loop is broken out of and `yield` is hit. The function exits and returns to its saved state on the next iteration. As such, `list()` can be called on the generator object to exhaust it fully and receive a list, as in your code. If no full list is desired, a generator is lighter than a full list.
- the `enumerate` function, together with list slicing, can do what your `range` code did. This way, the new code is a bit dense on that line; since it is also verbose, I think it's manageable. I find it to be more readable.

Comment: I really liked all the comments @alex-povel. Just a thought about the imports, I also find datetime.datetime confusing, but I think it is a built-in python problem. I usually try to respect Google Python Style Guide on that and use `import datetime`.

Comment: Well, nono, I mean: `from datetime import datetime` is confusing. `import datetime` and then using `datetime.datetime` is fine, as you said. Following the Google Python style guide is a good idea. My point was just that *if* `datetime.datetime` should be shortened, `from datetime import datetime` is **not** the way to go.